# Which has less energy loss - AC step up/step down transformers or DC to DC step up/down converters?

Tags: transformer, dc-dc-converter

In the EE field, AC transformers are constantly talked about. However, I don't hear much of DC to DC converter modules, even though DC is widely used today, mostly in smaller electronics.

Both of these perform similar operations by converting to a higher or lower voltage, but I am wondering which is better in terms of least amount of energy lost? I would assume that if transformers are not as efficient as these DC converters then AC would be rectified and then converted to higher voltage.

Comment: It depends.....

Comment: The desire may be for the SAME input and output voltage also. Common for isolation purposes.

Comment: An expensive DC/DC converter may outperform a cheap AC/AC transformer.  However as you go larger it becomes cheaper to reach high efficiency with a transformer by a modest increase in size while the technology a semiconductor switching has sort of finite limits in efficiency.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I don't hear much of DC to DC converter modules, even though DC is
>   widely used today, mostly in smaller electronics.

You might not have heard much about DC/DC converters because they are often built into the device. The vast majority of mains powered 'smaller electronics' today have switching AC/DC converters to produce low voltage DC from the AC mains. A switching AC/DC converter (also known as a switched-mode power supply or SMPS) consists of a mains voltage rectifier and filter, followed by a DC/DC converter. Many devices also have on-board DC/DC converters to further reduce voltage.

Mains frequency transformers are used less to power 'smaller electronics' today because they are more bulky and less efficient, especially once the output has been rectified, smoothed and regulated. Although the power loss in an individual device might be so low that the consumer doesn't consider the cost, there are so many of them that the total loss could be significant.

Transformers are used mostly to increase or decrease AC voltages for mains transmission and supply. Large transformers are more efficient than small ones, and cheaper and less complex than using a DC/DC intermediary when the the input and output are both AC. However at the other end of the scale, very long transmission lines and undersea cables have less loss using DC, even after DC/AC conversion at each end.

So in deciding which is more efficient you have to consider not just the component that changes the voltage, but what associated losses may occur in other parts of the system. In the case of 'smaller electronics' seemingly insignificant transformer losses could become a big problem when DC conversion losses and power factor are taken into account.

[Efficiency Standards for External Power Supplies](https://www.digikey.com/en/articles/techzone/2015/aug/efficiency-standards-for-external-power-supplies)

> In the early 90’s, it was estimated that there were more than one
>   billion external power supplies active in the United States alone. The
>   efficiency of these power supplies, mainly utilizing linear
>   technology, could be as low as 50% and still draw power when the
>   application was turned off or not even connected to the power supply
>   (referred to as “no-load” condition). **Experts calculated that without**
>   **efforts to increase efficiencies and reduce “no-load” power**
>   **consumption, external power supplies would account for around 30% of**
>   **total energy consumption in less than 20 years**.

Answer (score 6):

It’s important to compare apples to apples.

If you’re talking about long-lines distribution, HVDC *as a system* is more efficient due to the absence of skin effect in the conductor: current flows in the entire cable making the I2R losses much lower. Also, dielectric losses are reduced from those inherent with AC. The cable can therefore be sized without needing to allow for these losses (or, its carrying capacity can be increased.)

Taken together, these advantages make HVDC long lines about 30-40% more efficient than AC. This increased capacity and efficiency justifies the cost and conversion losses of the HVDC inverters at each end.

HVDC at scale also has the benefit of eliminating the need for inter-grid frequency or phase matching, allowing more manageable power routing for system operators.

More here: https://sinews.siam.org/Details-Page/direct-current-transmission-and-the-future-of-electricity

For medium and low voltage distribution, the simplicity and low cost of AC with transformers wins out. It’s hard to say if AC is *actually* more efficient than DC at this scale, given advances in conversion technologies since Edison and Tesla’s era. AC is however more *convenient*, especially for motors and some lighting systems.

Even in this realm however, the push for 48V DC data center power would suggest that different approaches using DC-DC are more efficient. Using local DC also simplifies battery integration for UPS systems, critical for guaranteed fault tolerance and uptime.

More here: https://web.archive.org/web/20160930183115/https://www.edn.com/design/power-management/4442710/2/48V-direct-conversion-dramatically-improves-data-center-energy-efficiency-

That said, even at smaller scale, for managing renewable power generation there is work going on with voltage-source conversion using local HVDC at tens to hundreds of kilovolts. This development, called ‘HVDC Light’, arose from using HVDC for offshore windmill plants where using undersea AC cabling was impractical, due to shield losses in the cable armor.

More here: https://library.e.abb.com/public/b35718ff8f3fa4c0c1256fda004c8ca2/VSC%20TRANSMISSION%20TECHNOLOGIES.pdf

In fact, the initial motivation for HVDC came from Sweden, where it was first employed with undersea cables linking the power grid from the mainland to neighboring islands. Engineers determined that HVDC avoided losses in the cable armor, greatly improving efficiency. More here: https://eepower.com/market-insights/65-years-of-hvdc/

Now for a power supply, note that when transforming from one voltage to another, there is usually some sort of AC and inductance involved, be it a step-down transformer, a DC-DC flyback, or some other inductive device, because inductors are really excellent energy transfer devices but need AC to work as such. The exact inductor topology will be depend on cost, efficiency, power handling, voltage, and other factors.

Comment: _"HVDC as a system is more efficient due to the absence of skin effect in the conductor"_ - I thought it was more efficient due to the absence of losses in capacitive coupling. Note that the skin depth of copper at 50Hz is 9mm, which is fairly large I think.

Comment: @marcelm A skin depth of 9mm is not so big if you want to transfer thousands of amperes across a large distance. On the other hand, capacitive coupling is small if the conductors are meters apart.

Comment: "HVDC as a system is more efficient due to the absence of skin effect in the conductor" that is not the whole truth. HVDC avoids the current to charge and discharge the cable capacitance, especially when cables are in the ground or undersea. These currents limit the length of undersea AC cables.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson At the same time, for transmission lines, pure conductors are often not mechanically ideal due to their material properties.  Compound conductors like [ACSR cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium-conductor_steel-reinforced_cable), for example, are one clever way that the structural requirements of the cable can be met while, at the same time, mitigating the problems of skin depth.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose it mostly matters what you're coming from and what you're going to, i.e. AC/AC, AC/DC, DC/DC, or DC/AC.  That said in a direct comparison between transformers vs. DC/DC converters, I'd wager transformers will have better efficiency.  Obviously there's lots of use case considerations such as input and output voltage differential, but generally, it's difficult to get much better than 90% effeciency out of a DC/DC converter. Where according to [this](https://www.electricaleasy.com/2014/04/transformer-losses-and-efficiency.html)...

> Most of the transformers have full load efficiency between 95% to 98.5%